# JasperReports hidden exception when filling compiled report

Tags: java, exception, groovy, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports 5.0.0 to make reports in my Java application.
When I load & compile report from `.jrxml` file it has no problem.
But when I try to load them from compiled report (`.jasper` file) it stops operation without any exception!
I surrounded `JasperFillManager.fillReport` statement with a try statement that catch `Throwable` like this:

```
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new FileInputStream(new File(Main.jarpath,Main.REPORT_TEMPLATE)));
try{
    jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
}catch(Throwable ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now it prints this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPogoCallCurrentSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallCurrentSite(CallSiteArray.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at pe_report_1367344395908_105126.customizedInit(calculator_pe_report_1367344395908_105126:87)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.init(JREvaluator.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.init(JRCalculator.java:111)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:469)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:529)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:82)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
        at pe.reporting$1.doInBackground(reporting.java:75)
        at pe.reporting$1.doInBackground(reporting.java:41)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classpath issue related to the groovy jar. If you are using groovy for your expressions you need to add the groovy jar to your classpath.

To find the one you need the easy way is to:

- Go look to the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports)
- Select the version of Jasper Reports you are using (i.e. [5.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.0.0))
- Find the listing for groovy and take notice of the version it needs. (For jasper 5.0 you need [groovy-all 2.0.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all))
- Then download the binary from the Maven Repository manually ([Link to groovy-all 2.0.1 jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.0.1/groovy-all-2.0.1.jar)).

If you are not using groovy in your report, you may be able to simply remove the `language` atrribute in the jasperReport xml tag in the jrxml altogether. This (at least in older versions) defaulted it to java usage for expressions.

Comment: yes i'm using it but it is in classpath (I have `groovy-all-1.5.5.jar` there); after that it has no problem when I'm not using pre-compiled report!! (using `.jrxml` and compiling it at runtime) I used my application methods in groovy (in report) is it possible that be the problem (my application class be not in groovy's class path?)

Comment: @4r1y4n Well for JasperReports 5.0.0 it says it needs `groovy-all-2.0.1.jar` so the only thing I can think is that you are essentially compiling the report using iReport that is using a newer version of groovy than what you are using to try to run it. So to me, basically a version mismatch is the most likely culprit.

Comment: The other option is to compile the jrxml in the app, and see if that works. If it does, maybe as part of your build you could have it precompile the reports you want, and handle it that way. Although it seems like more work than updating the jar.

Comment: Unfortunately changing to `groovy-all-2.0.1.jar` had no effect; still getting same exception!

Comment: when I'm compiling report in App itself its OK! just when it is pre-compiled this problem raises!

Comment: I believe the problem is with Groovy! I changed report language to Java and problem solved!!!

Comment: @4r1y4n I think I had not explained my self well, and I apologize for that. Essentially what ever version of iReport you were using, was using a different version of groovy when it was compiling the report, than what you were using when you executed the report. And when I said `if you are not using groovy in your report` I was referring to using groovy expressions in expression fields of the report. Glad you got it working, I know it can frustrating at times.